# How can I write more values to a pipe and read them?

Tags: c++, linux, process, pipe

I write a program in c++ under linux where a child process should write two long values into a pipe and the parent process should read them. Until now, I onlz manages to set up two (named) pipes for this and write each one by write(fd1,&value1,sizeof(long)) and read it by read(fd1, &value1, sizeof(long)).
Just one pipe for both would be nicer but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

I tried:

```
write(fd1,&value1,sizeof(long));

write(fd1,&value2,sizeof(long));
```

and two reads as well but this seems to lead to processes blocking and waiting for each other.

I would be very glad if someone could give me a hint, how to realize this.

Possible SOLUTION: I wrote all the values in an array (because i knew how many), then i needed only one wire/read call.

Comment: The pipes may be buffered did you flush them?

Answer (score 3):

It should work fine.  Here is a very simple example.  It is mostly a copy of code [from the example in the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int fd[2];
   pid_t cpid;
   int ret;
   int val = 0;
   if (pipe(fd) == -1)
      {
      perror("pipe"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   cpid = fork();
   if (cpid == -1)
      {
      perror("fork"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   if (cpid == 0) { 
      // close write end of pipe in child
      close(fd[1]);   
      ret = read(fd[0], &val, sizeof( val ));
      printf( "1: result = %d, value = %d\n", ret, val );
      ret = read(fd[0], &val, sizeof( val ));
      printf( "2: result = %d, value = %d\n", ret, val );
      close(fd[0]);
      _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      } 
   else {
      // close read end of pipe in parent
      close(fd[0]); 
      val = 42;
      if ( write(fd[1], &val, sizeof(val)) < 0 )
         perror( "write" );
      val++;
      if ( write(fd[1], &val, sizeof(val)) < 0 )
         perror( "write" );
      close(fd[1]); 
      wait(NULL); 
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the return value of your read(), the two longs will eventually (and probably) be sent together to the receiving process. In this case you need to split the received buffer into two longs.